# Can't get Select event at GridView in userControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, code-behind, web-user-controls, webusercontrols

I have button and GridView at UserControl.
When I press button.It will perform at PageLoad function.
But when I click select in GridView.It can't work same button at PageLoad.

```
 if (!IsPostBack){}             
 else{
                    string str_btn = null;
                    if (Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1]!=null)
                        str_btn=Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1].ToString();
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str_btn))
                       handleClick(str_btn);
                    else
                        Response.Redirect("../Ipservice/IpserviceDevices.aspx?btn=ipservice", false);
                }
```

Do you have any solution for resolved this issues.

I wondered if you share your knowledge

**IpInterfaceUC UserControl**

```
<div id="dvChannel" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvChannelUC" 
            OnRowCommand="gvChannelUC_RowCommand"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvChannel_SelectedIndexChanged"
        />
</div>
```

**IPServices page CodeBehind**

```
if (!IsPostBack){
}else
{    
 string str_btn = Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1].ToString();
 handleClick(str_btn);
}
```

**Question**

It always show **str_btn** is null.If I click Button,It'll show button's id.But when I click Select at GridView,It show **str_btn** is null.It should be show GridView's id when we click select.

Thanks for any explain.

Comment: Where is the GridView markup? There is no reference to GridView in your question?

Comment: GridView is in UserControl.I click gridview event on aspx page.

Comment: I edit my description issues.I wondered if you share me any your solution.Thanks

Comment: Your GridView does not have a select button. At least your GridView should have `AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"`. And why are you not using the normal event handlers like Button_Click, GridView_RowCommand?

Comment: Yes,I did it.But it didn't work.My description just bref code,It just have main code.I hide some code in this description

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22446/discussion-between-binh-tieu-and-codingbiz)

Comment: Hi brother,Because my project need add more than 1 Devices

Comment: Devices is same as UserControl
So that,I need design more than a Devices
It'll dynamic Devices

Comment: Are u there?May we discuss something?